# How to fix error " Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar "?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

how to fix this error: `Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar` in `ionic build android`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have upgraded Gradle to latest version, and using the old maven-gradle-plugin.

Here you have two options,

1. upgrade android-maven-gradle-plugnin to latest version. [Check here to choose right plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin)
2. downgrade gradle to previous version

Comment: how to know version gradle ?

Comment: Thank You Sir . I'm upgrade android-maven-gradle to version 2.0 . Now APK has been generate . Thank you.. You save my life . Good Answer

Comment: @LulzSec you can find distributionUrl  in <project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties